# How to Draw a "Class" in Java on a JPanel

Tags: java, swing

Currently I am using a JFrame that has a JPanel in it. In my JPanel I have overridden the paint component method, However, I want to "draw" a "Hero" class as a unit. Let me elaborate. The hero class as of right now has two parts: A health bar and an image. Originally, in the paint component method of my JPanel, I was drawing the character and health bar individually.

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        g.drawImage(h.getImage(), h.getX(), h.getY(),null);
        g.setColor(Color.red);
        g.fillRect(h.getX()+7, h.getY()-16, 50, 10);
        g.drawLine(h.getX() + (h.getImage().getWidth(getFocusOwner())/2), h.getY()-40, h.getX() + (h.getImage().getWidth(getFocusOwner())/2), h.getY()+40);


    }
```

This properly aligned the health bar and character together, however, this seemed inefficient and messy. So, is there anyway I could draw the two together as a unit? I pondered making them a separate JPanel, but realized that was a silly idea. Is there anyway to do this more efficiently? One of the biggest reasons i am looking for a solution now is that i would like to be able to extend the character class with other classes IE: Monster, Knight, Goblin but when i draw them their respective health bars and images lined up. If you need any further explanation please ask. Thank you!

Also, to spark any ideas that you might have, I'm imagining something like this. Another thing: Would using canvas be of any use?

```
paint(Hero);
```

Thank you again!

Comment: Usually it's the other way around: `hero.paint()`

Comment: I wouldn't really know. I've never painted a whole class. Do you need to override a method like paintComponent has to be overridden for JPanel?

Answer (score 3):

In your `Hero` class define a drawing method which accepts a `Graphics` object:

```
public void drawHero(Graphics g)
{
    // implementation
}
```

Then in your main `JPanel` subclass draw the `Hero` with this drawing method:

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{
    // other drawing code

    hero.drawHero(g);
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be something more like g.draw(hero.drawHero(g));?

Comment: @SteveKnabe No, the `Graphics` class does not contain a `draw` method. You must implement your own basic method and then pass the `Graphics` object around.

Comment: Oh i see now. In the heros drawHero method you're editing the graphics in the paintComponent parameters. Thank you very much!